# TimePickerDialog popup on start of the apps

Tags: android, datetimepicker

Im trying to make datepickerdialog and timepickerdialog to popup when clicked on textview. I have a problem where every time I started my apps the TimePickerDialog pop up itself eventhough I didn't even click on the text box yet. Any way I can fix this issue?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{
EditText e_tarikh, e_masa;
String tarikh, masa;
private DBOperations db;
private EditText fromDateEtxt;
private EditText toTimeEtxt;
private int mHour, mMinute;

private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
private TimePickerDialog toTimePickerDialog;

private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DBOperations(this);
    e_tarikh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tarikh);
    e_masa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.masa);


    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
    findViewsById();
    setDateTimeField();

}
public void saveData(View view)
{

    tarikh = e_tarikh.getText().toString();
    masa = e_masa.getText().toString();

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute("add_info", tarikh, masa);
    finish();
}


private void findViewsById() {
    fromDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tarikh);
    fromDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    fromDateEtxt.requestFocus();

    toTimeEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.masa);
    toTimeEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
}

private void setDateTimeField() {
    fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    toTimeEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    toTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {

                    e_masa.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    toTimePickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == fromDateEtxt) {
        fromDatePickerDialog.show();
    } else if(view == toTimeEtxt) {
        toTimePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `setDateTimeField();` line from onCreate() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is remove line below from your `setDateTimeField()` method, because you don't want to show `toTimePickerDialog` until you click on your button or textView. Now it is in your onCreate method, so it runs every time you run your app.

```
toTimePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its becuase your creating timePicker in `onCreate()` by calling this `setDateTimeField();` method
Remove TimePicker From your `setDateTimeField();` method:

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
    fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    toTimeEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    //Remove this
    /*toTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {

                    e_masa.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    toTimePickerDialog.show();*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this line:

```
toTimePickerDialog.show();
```

from your

```
setDateTimeField()
```